# How to loop through columns using slice_min

Tags: r, loops, slice, apply, lapply

I have a large matrix (3918 rows x3919 cols; see link attached) indicating dissimilarity measures between 3918 people (one extra row for ID)
For each person (column) I want to select 10 nearest neighbors (rows with smallest dissimilarity). I tried using the slice_min function but don't know how to loop trough the columns. Is there an easy way to select each columns' nearest neighbors' ID in an iterative function and store them all in one new object?

I tried:
slice_min(dissimilarity_mtrx, order_by = ID_1, with_ties = FALSE, n = 10)[ ,1]
which turns out correct (extract IDs via [ ,1])
but I couldn't find a way to loop the "order_by" argument.

I was also thinking about "for loop" or "(l)apply" functions but don't know how to combine it with slice_min.

Thanks for any ideas !

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I concur with @RonakShah. A representative sample would tremendously help. If you struggle with `(l)apply()` and friends, read up on `dplyr` and `across()`. Obviously for this you have to convert your matrix into a dataframe/tibble. With the latter helper function you can walk over columns. If needed `rowwise()` gives you a row-by-row way of data manipulation. That is an easy to understand way to iterate over dataframe rows (if you feel uncomfortable with other iteration approaches).